# Framework for plotting graphs in ios which supports ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to plot a graph for number of visits of a website on a weekly basis.I need to show this information plotted on a graph in an iphone app.As ARC is used in my iphone project, it is hard for me to implement CorePlot as it does not use ARC.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn `ARC off` for CorePlot by setting this `-fno-objc-arc` flag to it's source files by selecting your project file in XCode, selecting your target, going to 'Build Phases'->'Compile Sources'

- Navigate to Target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources
- Select your desired files
- Add the compiler flag -fno-objc-arc

if you dont like above solution then you can use [EcGraph](https://code.google.com/p/ecgraph/)